# How to realize the death of a character if a box falls on his head in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to make a 2d game.
The question is: There is a box with which the character can interact, while nothing should happen. If the box falls on the head of a character with a certain speed, the character must die, how to implement it?

Comment: The issue is resolved: In OnCollisionEnter, all information comes in the form of a Collision object and there is also a speed there

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-relativeVelocity.html

Comment: **Please use the correct tags!**     How is this related to `unity-container` (has absolutely nothing to do with Unity3d whatsoever!), `visual-studio` (the IDE you are using doesn't matter - this question is not about a specific IDE), `facebook-unity-sdk` (... your question isn't even slightly touching facebook related stuff), `unityscript` (this is a **deprecated** language used in early Unity versions .. you most probably are not looking for solutions in that language ...)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use overlapcircle to check if the box touch his Head if the box touch his head and the falling speed of the box is equal somthing then the player will dead

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).